# Screen Halt while Communication(Client/Server) in Android

Tags: android, client-server, communication

I have an application in which there is Google map, location overlays on Google map and a separate thread which send the current location of device to server after every 30 seconds. The problem is that when the thread sends the location to server the screen of device halted until the server respond. Here is the following code,

Global Object

```
private Handler handlerTimer = new Handler();
```

In onCreate Method

```
 handlerTimer.removeCallbacks(taskUpdateStuffOnDialog );
 handlerTimer.postDelayed(taskUpdateStuffOnDialog , 100);
```

And here is the `taskUpdateStuffOnDialog`

```
    private Runnable taskUpdateStuffOnDialog = new Runnable() 
    {        
        public void run() 
        { 
        try
        { 
        URL url3 = new URL("http://"+ appState.getURL()+"//iLocator/IDForClient.php?reg_no="+ Device_ID[0]);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url3.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String quote = reader.readLine();
        while (quote != null)
        {
            Device_ID = quote.split("\n");
            quote = reader.readLine();
            bCheckID = true;
        }//End While

        positionOverlay.setID(Device_ID[0]);
        addEvent(Device_ID[0]);

    }//End try
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainMapActivity.this, "Communication Issue",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
    }//End catch
handlerTimer.postDelayed(this, 9000);
        }

    };
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you're not really spawning a separate thread to send the location to the server. Most likely your blocking the Main UI thread somehow.  I can't really tell what's happening from the code you posted.

Comment: @Dbryson, I have edited my question please check it now.

Comment: See me post below. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, although you're spawning a new Thread, you aren't spawning a new *process*. Everything you're doing is still in the user interface process, and that's blocking. You can find more information on the topic [on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html).

The quickest and easiest way to get around this is using the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class. It will only allow one HTTP request to be executed at a time, but will take care of all the problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the AsyncTask for connecting to the Server.  See an example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html